# How to compare individual properties of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

1. I have a single array of objects.
2. The objects are different variations of this:

```
{
    "animals": {
        "name": "elephant",
        "diet": "herbivore",
        "color": "spotted",
        "age": "12",
        "numbers": ["11", "10", "24", "9"]
    }
}
```

How to iterate through the collection and determine if there are differences between the "numbers" properties or "diet" properties? As in:

*In the array, 50 elephant object's "diet" property read "herbivore", but one it reads "omnivore". Break out because it's different and report it.*

Or as in:

*In the array, 70 elephant object's "numbers" property are the same (even if some are out of order). Report they are the same.*

**What did I try?:**

1. Stringifying the objects and comparing them, but that won't work because I'm not trying to compare whole objects (just a few individual properties).
2. I can make this work with a for loop, but it seems stupid overkill and not very efficient for a collection that potentially has hundreds of objects in it.

This is pseudo code, don't freak out:

```
var isValid = true;

//go through each element in the array
for(let i = 0, i < array.length, i++) {
    //check if you have exceeded length of the array
    if(i + 1 <= array.length) {

        //sort the numbers
        var sortedLowerNumbers = sortFunction(array[i].numbers);
        var sortedhigherNumbers = sortFunction(array[i+1].numbers);
        //compare equality 
       isValid = json.stringify(sortedLowerNumbers) === json.stringify(sortedhigherNumbers);
        
       if(!isValid) {
         break
       }
    }
}
```

**My research**

None of the questions seem applicable. They're seem to be either [comparing multiple arrays rather than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286671/comparing-two-json-arrays) or [comparing entire JSON objects for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412576/comparing-values-in-json-object-array) rather than comparing individual properties.

**Is there a smarter way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

Although a for loop is the best and most simple way to do it. if you are looking for brevity you can use [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
let arr = [{
        name: "elephant",
        diet: "herbivore",
        color: "spotted",
        age: "12",
       numbers: ["11", "10", "24","9"]
},{             name: "elephant",
        diet: "herbivore",
        color: "spotted",
        age: "12",
       numbers: ["11", "10", "24","9"]
},{
                name: "elephant",
        diet: "herbivore",
        color: "spotted",
        age: "12",
       numbers: ["11", "10", "24","9" , "23"]
}];
let arrSort = arr[0].numbers.sort();
let JSONarrSort = JSON.stringify(arrSort);
console.log(arr.every(x => JSON.stringify(x.numbers.sort()) === JSONarrSort));
console.log(arr.every(x => x.diet === arr[0].diet));
```

Comment: From the OP: `In the array, 50 elephant object's "diet" property read "herbivore", but one it reads "omnivore". Break out because it's different and report it.`. So, should we consider the second `console` be changed to something like: `arr.some(x => x.diet !== arr[0].diet`?